# How do I reference a Cloudflare Durable Object in wrangler.toml

Tags: cloudflare-workers

I have a Cloudflare Worker which uses Durable Objects. I have based my application on the chat demo code and everything has been working fine up till now but my code base is becoming too big to realistically maintain in a single file. I have tried refactoring my durable object code to put my class in a separate file and then importing it in my main file but I get an error on publish: "New version of script does not export class which is depended on by existing Durable Objects".

Can I have my Durable Object stored in a separate file and if so how do I get Cloudflare to recognise it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-`export`the Durable Object class that you import.

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick. Just by way of elaboration for anyone else stumbling across this, if you are importing as so: import {MyObject} from "./my_objects/myObject.mjs", simply change the import keyword to export and it will be picked up by Cloudflare. Thank you!